# what's the difference between access token(Oauth1) and bearer token(Oauth2)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am pretty new to OAuth2 standard, I am wondering what's the difference between access token(Oauth1) and bearer token(Oauth2). Is bearer token a kind of access token? What does bearer stands for?

Answer (score 3):

An access token in OAuth 1.0 is presented on a protected resource request along with a signature across all parameters in that request. The access token definition in OAuth 2.0 is more flexible. One implementation is a bearer access token where the presenter of the token gets access to the protected resource without further signing of the request. As the spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750 puts it:

> Any party in possession of a bearer token (a "bearer") can use
> it to get access to    the associated resources (without demonstrating
> possession of a    cryptographic key).

OAuth 2.0 allows for other types of access tokens as well, including ones that require so-called "proof of possession" (PoP) as in OAuth 1.0 but the standard for that is under development, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-pop-architecture.

Note one major difference is that bearer tokens can only be used on TLS protected channels because leakage must be prevented, whereas PoP tokens (in OAuth 1.0 and 2.0) can be used on plain HTTP too.